# How to specify that an argument is optional in flask-restful

Tags: flask-restful

I have code like this:

```py
def delete(self, rid):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('rating', default=2, type=int, help='blablabla')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    rating = args['rating']
    ...
    return {'message': message}
```

This still asks me for the `rating` param, and throws `400 Bad Request` if no exist.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 8):

Try `required=False`:

```
parser.add_argument('rating', default=2, required=False, type=int, help='blablabla')
```

and check for `rating` in `args` (`if 'rating' in args: pass`).